# Opera 11.50 won't play sounds or animate page title on Facebook

Tags: opera, facebook

I have the version 11.50 and when I am on facebook chat, it won't play any sound when a new chat message is arrived neither animate the page title. I have checked the "play sound" on the chat box.

I had this problem since the previous version that I first installed Opera.

Comment: do you mean previous version had the same issue ?

Comment: Yes, I had this issue, updated today but still the same. Everything works fine on FF, Chrome, Seamonkey

Comment: In Opera, follow these three very simple steps to report this (or any other) bug directly to the developers:  Navigate to _the problem page_ -> Help menu -> Report a Site Problem...

Comment: @Karokotsiros What version of windows are you using?

Comment: I am on windows 7

Comment: Have you checked out the **sound mixer** to see if it's on mute for Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug in Opera , you will have to wait for it .
I googled this issue and came across a couple of site both non-english :-(
 and there are other people facing the issue .
My suggestion follow Randolf's suggestion and wait for the Opera guys to figure this out, mean while use another browser for Facebook if the bug bugs you too much :)